# Show in textview html with inline styles

Tags: android, html, css, textview, inline-styles

I need to show html with **inline styles** in my app. 
There are a lot of text that must be in **different views** so I can't use Webview(I tried to use a lot of Webviews but the app becomes very slow ).As I know TextView can show html but it can`t show html with inline styles. 
So, what should I do? 
Is there any way to show it or to generate only html with simple tags from html with **inline styles**?

So I need to show html like this:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 36pt; font-family: 'comic sans ms', sans-serif;">Article Title</span></p>
```

But TextView can`t understand style.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android native `TextView` doesn't support all HTML tags and features. It only does support a [few tags and properties](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html). So, in your case, there's a couple of options which you may want to consider.

- Use `WebView` to show rich texts. However, `WebView`s are too heavy and slow.
- Use 3rd party libraries that improve native `TextView` and support more HTML tags. For example: [HTML-TextView](https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview).

Comment: Thank you  for answer but the main problem is that I need to use inline styles.

Comment: @sofi37 Sorry, Android `TextView`s don't support `style` property. You may want to instead use `WebView`.

Comment: @sofi37 What do you want to do with `style` property? Only color?

Comment: @Hiimfrogatto  Webview is too heavy and I need to use a couple of them.

Comment: @sofi37 Color and font size are fine and are supported by `TextView`.

Comment: @Hiimfrogatto Not only color. Also align, font size, font color,font family, and others.

Comment: @Hiimfrogatto I got the package with html inline styles from back-end so I can`t change it to attributes. The only thing what I can do is to parse it but it is not so simple.

Comment: @sofi37 Okay, so, consider using `WebView`.

Comment: @sofi37 However, if you'd want to parse, consider [jSoup] and [HTMLcleaner].

Comment: @Hiimfrogatto but then app is too slow as I use for example 15 webviews

Comment: @Hiimfrogatto Thank you I will look on  [jSoup] and [HTMLcleaner].

Answer (score 0):

Only one way to implement this is to use a 3rd party libraries as alternative for Android `Html.fromHtml ()` method like [this](https://github.com/NightWhistler/HtmlSpanner), which supports a CSS attributes, so for example

`<div style="font-weight:bold;">bold text</div>`

become

`<b>bold text</b>`