# A <img> in a TextView with fromHtml

Tags: android, html, textview

I want to load an image in a `TextView` with `fromHtml`

In the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691287/show-in-textview-html-with-inline-styles) a `<img src="your_link">` should work in a TextView, but I only get a green square, see image below:

[image: Result]

This is the HTML that's loaded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<body> 
<h1>Image</h1> 
<img src="http://hanassets.nd.gov/images/product/test.png"> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show your implementation of showing HTML in TextView

Comment: I use databinding:
`android:text='@{Html.fromHtml(message != null ? message : "")}'`

Comment: Do you have Internet permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading an image with  is not possible using fromHtml() method. This method just helps you get the text styling from html

Comment: I think you're right, I'm now using a `WebView` instead

Comment: WebView will do the needful. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot, but did you add the permission in the android manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```