# Show html string with inline style attribute in android text view

Tags: android, html, kotlin, textview, rs

I want to show html text with inline style sheet in android text view developed in kotlin with RS. The Html text which i want to show is given below : 
I have already tried solution given in

[Show in textview html with inline styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691287/show-in-textview-html-with-inline-styles)

but it is not helpful for me.

My html text is like this with inline style attribute

```
<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'> 4x<span  style='font-size:6.0pt;line-height:137%;position:relative;top:-3.5pt'>–1/4</span> is  expressed as</p><img src=\"http://developer.android.com/assets/images/dac_logo.png\">
<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'>–4x<span  style='font-size:6.0pt;line-height:137%;position:relative;top:-3.5pt'>1/4</span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'>x<span  style='font-size:6.0pt;line-height:137%;position:relative;top:-3.5pt'>–1</span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'>4/x<span  style='font-size:6.0pt;line-height:137%;position:relative;top:-3.5pt'>1/4</span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'>None of  these</p>
```

**HTML View**

4x<sup>–1/4</sup> is  expressed as

–4x<sup>1/4</sup>

x<sup>–1</sup>

4/x<sup>1/4</sup>

None of  these

**In text view I have tried html text but** 
instead of

X<sup>2</sup> + Y<sup>2</sup> = Z<sup>2</sup>

it is coming like

X2 + Y2 = Z2

Answer (score 1):

Either:

- Use a `WebView`, or
- Create a `SpannedString` yourself (instead of using HTML), or
- Create a `SpannedString` using libraries like [this](https://github.com/neworld/spanner) or [this](https://github.com/yombunker/SpanEZ), or
- Switch to [Markdown](https://github.com/noties/Markwon) (perhaps using LaTeX for your formulas), or
- Use [custom text widgets that support HTML parsing](https://github.com/SysdataSpA/SDHtmlTextView)
- Use [custom widgets that handle LaTeX for formulas](https://github.com/lingarajsankaravelu/Katex)